# A batch file for sorting images into folders by shooting date

Tags: windows

What would be the easiest way to sort a lot of images that are currently residing in one directory into subdirectories each named after the date of the shooting of the image?

Is there a utility or a batch script for something like that?

I imagine I'm not the first who thought of this, but suprisingly, couldn't find anything on photo.SE until now.

Comment: Possible relevant [answer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48721/how-can-i-find-all-sets-of-photos-taken-on-the-same-date-across-years) (check my scripting).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about moving files into directories, but take a look at Namexif, which will rename files according to the date they were shot - it might be useful to you:

http://www.digicamsoft.com/softnamexif.html

With some Perl scripting ability, it shouldn't be too hard to write your own script for moving files into directories, using something like ExifTool:

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Edit: Indeed, I just took another look at ExifTool, and it has the functionality you're looking for built in. See description here:

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/filename.html